# Homology of 2-sheeted covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces

Let $p: P\to X$ be a 2-sheeted covering space over X.
Consider $$ 0\to C_n(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)   \stackrel{\tau}{\to}   C_n(P;\mathbb{Z}_2) \stackrel{p_{\#}}{\to} C_n(X;\mathbb{Z}_2) \to 0. $$
where $\tau(\sigma)=\tilde{\sigma_1}+\tilde{\sigma_2}$ and $\tilde{\sigma_1},\tilde{\sigma_2}$ are two distinct lifts of $\sigma: \Delta^n\to X.$
Show above sequence is exact for all $n\geq0$ and that they form SES of chain complexes (i.e. they are chain maps?).
In associated LES describe connecting homomorphism $$\partial: H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)\to H_{n-1}(X;\mathbb{Z}_2) $$ on the level of chains $c_1=[01]+[02]+[12]$ and $c_1=[012]+[013]+[023]+[123]$.

What property of covering spaces should I use? I'm totaly puzzled by the task and don't know where to start. Thanks fo help.

Comment: To show injectivity of $\tau$ try and show that $\tau$ comes from an injective chain map $f:C_n(X) \rightarrow C_n(P)$, i.e $\tau = f \otimes \mathbb Z_2$. Since tensoring preserves injectivity of maps between projective groups if $f$ is injective then $\tau$ will be injective aswell. Showing surjectivity of $p_ \#$ comes from the fact that every $\sigma: \Delta^n \rightarrow X$ has a lift along $p$. To show that $p_\# \circ \tau = 0$ note that $(p_\# \circ \tau) (\sigma) = p_\# (\bar \sigma_1 + \bar \sigma_2) = 2 \sigma$ since $p \circ 
\bar \sigma_1 = p \circ \bar \sigma_2$.

Comment: And then since $2 = 0$ in $\mathbb Z_2$, $(p_\# \circ \tau)(\sigma) = 0$